# What Google Cloud Platform product/service to get View Count

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics

I am wanting to get reliable statistics of how many times a certain profile (and it's unique route) has been viewed so that I may show that view count in the profile.  What GCP product/service/method will make this possible?  Was also thinking that I could somehow already utilize the Google Analytics data that's already plugged into my platform, but don't know of an api to get this information or if that is even best practice.

I am currently using GCP App Engine, GCP Storage - deploying a postgresql DB and React frontend.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think there are a world of different solutions to this.  By profile ... do you mean a "user profile" held as a database record?  If so, then I'm imagining that there is some logic in your code that retrieves and builds the profile response (some form of getProfile() function).  My immediate architecture solution would be that the record has a "count" field which gets incremented when getProfile() is called.  Another story would be to use StackDriver metrics and publish a metric.  You could then use Stackdriver aggregation to calculate the views.

Comment: If all you need is just showing the count of the profile visualization the "count" field in database, as @Kolban said, would be the most suitable. You do not need a tool just for that.

Comment: That's a great and simple solution - ha, why didn't I think of that.  That should work for now! Thank you @kolban